# How to start Chrome Developer Tools' profiler or audit exactly at the moment web page starts to load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

Chrome's Developer Tools have big beautiful `Start` and `Run` buttons on `Profiles` and `Audits` pages respectively.

So, one can open web page then press these buttons to run analysis afterwards.

Is it possible to analyze one page load exactly, i.e. to run these tools exactly when page load starts and stop analysis exactly when last autorun javascript stops?

Comment: If you open developer tools and refresh your page, the recording starts automatically and stops when the page has loaded. I could see this in the Timeline tab and the data was displayed after that.

Comment: Please check this link, am sure you'll get a wealth of information in it and most probably a solution too !  https://github.com/paulirish/automated-chrome-profiling/blob/master/readme.md#timeline-recording-example